# probability of picking 1 item out of 100 items after 10 tries

Tags: probability

out of a pool of 100 items what is the probability of getting 1 item after 10 tries? The items will not be placed back again.

would it be correct to sum the percentages like the following?

EDIT FORMULA.
probability = 1/ 100 + 1/(100-1)...1/(100-9)

thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By $1/10*100$ do you mean $\frac 1{10} \cdot 100$ or $\frac 1{10\cdot 100}$?  If the first, the probability is greater than $1$.  If the second, the chance of success the first time is claimed to be $\frac 1{1000}$, which is clearly not right.

Comment: There are $\binom{100}{10}$ ways to pick $10$ items. And $\binom{99}{10}$ ways to choose $10$ items that are not the one you want.

Comment: Are you looking for the probability of obtaining this object on tenth sampled item? Or can you obtain this object on any of your ten tries?

Comment: @ross im sorry i edited my question. it is 1/100 without the 1/10 part.

Comment: @matt any of the tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use that. Because your formula is only true if you pick it out at the 10th trial, but not 1st, 2nd, 3rd...

The right method is to calculate the probability of not picking out the item and subtract it from 1. So $P=1-(99/100)(98/99)(97/98)…(90/91)$